# How to provide sfdc org Link for Guest User

Tags: community, email-template

In email template,

Using

> Please click on the link below link to view the record.
>
> ```
> Link to SFDC Record: {!Account.Link}
> ```

Problem is ,If site Guest user submits the record it shows partner portal link,instead if SFDC org Link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{!Account.Link}` is called as Detail Link. This Link Field does not exist on the Account table. Salesforce on runtime decided based on logged in user what should be the detail link(internal or partner/communities/portal/guest) and then uses same in the email template.

So, there is no way you can configure that behaviour.

What you can do is,

Create a formula field,

Link_Custom__c having value as

```
"https://yourinstance.salesforce.com/" + TEXT(ID)"
```

here: yourinntsacte is your salesforce org instance like EU6,AP1,NA3 etc. It can also be your myDomain url.

and then use Link_Custom__c in your email templates.

To make it more generic, You can use Hierarchical custom settings instead of hardcoding formula's with the instance url, to make it flexible for all orgs/sandboxes. This can be possible as we can access Hierarchical custom settings in formula fields.

Thus if you use it that way your Link_Custom__C formula will be

```
$Setup.My_Custom_Setting__c.Salesforce_Base_URL__C + ID
```

Comment: I need to keep this in: custom settings -> https://instance.salesforce.com/...Can you explain in your answer ..little more